# How to promisify a function using q and how to manage error handling?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, es6-promise, q

I have a function which i have promisifed using 'es6-promisify'. I want to replicate the functionality using 'q'.

Here is a sample code which i'm using:

```
const promisify = require('es6-promisify')

function asyncFunction (done) {
  console.time('asyncFunction')
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.timeEnd('asyncFunction')
    done()
  }, 500)
}

const asyncFunctionPromise = promisify(asyncFunction)
```

Also, lets say I get an error while running a said function which I have promisified. How do I handle those errors?

Comment: Docs: https://github.com/kriskowal/q#using-deferreds

Comment: Please show us, what you already tried rewriting with ``Q``. Otherwise it's hard to know how to help you.

Comment: It worked for me now

Comment: @Joel: The documentation really helped.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have been messing around with the 'q' library for quite some time today and finally think I have figured out a way.

Here's what I did and it was quite simple, now that i think about it.

```
const q = require('q')

function asyncFunction (done) {
  console.time('asyncFunction')
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.timeEnd('asyncFunction')
    done()
  }, 500)
}

const asyncFunctionPromise = q.denodeify(asyncFunction)
```

Just instead of

```
const promisify = require('es6-promisify')
```

use

```
const q = require('q')
```

and replace

```
const asyncFunctionPromise = promisify(asyncFunction)
```

with

```
const asyncFunctionPromise = q.denodeify(asyncFunction)
```

Also regarding the error handling: Handle the errors within the function. the Promise with automatically handle those errors.

PS: You can also use q.deferred to create Promises. It has similar syntax to jQuery.deferred.

Hope this helps someone with issues regarding broken Promises (Pun Intended.)